# Protractor Tests in Mac and iOS Giving ETIMEDOUT Error

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, appium

I am trying to run protractor tests on Mac-Chrome and iOS-Safari browsers. The test suite is triggered from a test machine. A selenium and Appium server is running in a remote Mac machine which takes care of Mac-Chrome and iOS-Safari Runs. Test machines talks to these servers to execute tests on Mac. On triggering the suite, a bunch of spec files error out with the message 'Error: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT :4444' for Mac and 'Error: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT :4723' for Appium.

Detailed Error:

```
Stack:
Error: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT 3.70.211.54:4444
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:174:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:259:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
From: Task: WebDriver.findElements(By.id("-example"))
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:362:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.findElements (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:1002:17)
    at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:137:30
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:382:21)
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:78:17)
    at [object Object].ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:711:7)
    at D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\e2e\util\helper.js:46:45
    at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:720:12
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
From: Task: <anonymous>
    at new wrappedCtr (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2468:26)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
From: Task: <anonymous wait>
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.wait (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:716:21)
    at Object.waitForElementAsSpecified (D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\e2e\util\helper.js:45:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\e2e\ng-specs\MyElement\some-spec.js:190:16)
    at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:96:23
    at new wrappedCtr (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2468:26)
    at controlFlowExecute (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:82:18)
From: Task: Run it("press enter arrow key") in control flow
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
    at attemptAsync (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1819:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1774:9)
    at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1801:16
    at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1745:9
    at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:18:5
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
From asynchronous test: 
Error
    at Suite.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\e2e-hdx\ng-specs\Someelement\Someelement-spec.js:188:5)
    at addSpecsToSuite (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:743:25)
    at Env.describe (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:713:7)
    at jasmineInterface.describe (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3219:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\e2e-hdx\ng-specs\Someelement\Someelement-spec.js:18:1)
```